# Texstudio- Check spelling inline but not automatically

Tags: texstudio, spelling

TexStudio underlines words while I type them (because "becau" is not a word). I would like TexStudio to underline misspelled words inline, but only check when I tell it to. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to switch this on and off is `Options -> Editor -> Inline Checking -> Spelling`.

Comment: That turns off inline checking completely. Is there a way to do what I want to do?

Comment: As said, this is the only way to influence inline spell checking.